# Express 4 with Basic Auth complains with "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, mongoose, basic-authentication

I want to auth users that try to access the edit functionality of my mean application.

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
```

...

```
var auth = function (req, res, next) {
    function unauthorized(res) {
        res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    };

    var user = basicAuth(req);

    if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
        return unauthorized(res);
    };

    config.administrators.forEach(function(admin){
        if (admin.email == user.name){
            if (admin.pwhash == (md5(admin.salt + user.pass))){
                req.admin = admin;
                return next();
            }
        }
    });
    return unauthorized(res);
};

router.get('/edit/', auth, function(req, res) {
    models.QuizModel.find({'author':req.admin.email}, function (err, quizes){
        res.status(200).send({'quizes': quizes});
    });
});

app.use('/api', router);
```

But all I get upon successful authentication is the following error message:

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:151:21)
    at C:\nodejs\projects\demo\server.js:69:19
    at C:\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

If I remove the mongoose find on the model, and directly send a response with some bogus information, I still get the error that I can't set the headers after they are sent, but the app won't crash and I'll actually be able to get to the next page. But I need to understand the underlying problem in my approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `return next()` from the `forEach` callback. As soon as next() is called the 2nd callback of the router is called and sends status of 200. Then it goes back to auth function, completes iteration and and calls `unauthorized(res)` which sends 401 status again.

So just replace `forEach`  with a `for` loop.

Comment: Hello hassansin,
thank you for your quick answer! This fixed my problem. I assumed that forEach would break upon return, but I was surprised to see that with a normal for-loop everything worked as expected.